# Shortest encoding for 32 bytes of data

Tags: python, encoding, hash, hex, base64

I have 32 bytes of binary data that I want to encode. It will be put in a URL so something URL safe is preferable. Obviously the typical encoding of choice is hex. This results in a 64 character string.

I've spend a lot of time looking at various encodings and was wondering, after failing to find, if there is some encoding that can produce an output less than 64 characters but **without padding** (just for URL cleanliness, I'd rather not have padding). A valid option would be something like a version of Base 64 that automatically determines, when decoding back to binary, whether padding was necessary.

It seems like Base 64 should be able to determine what the correct amount of padding was without the "=" characters being present as you can add an arbitrary number of "=" symbols to the end of a base 64 string and it will always decode successfully (at least using Python's `base64.b64decode()`). I could manually strip and re-add the padding to base 64 encoded strings, but for my use case, that will be a LOT of additional string manipulation.

Comment: If you're really concerned about performance (don't prematurely optimize) the best solution is probably to write your own Base64 encoder that leaves off the padding, and write a decoder that uses a lookup table (it's really not that complicated). From my own experience, most encoders/decoders that are included with languages or encoding libraries aren't optimized for speed (I can't speak directly to python though).

Comment: @Syon this is a very late stage optimization. We're exposing an internal API, that's been used by multiple platforms for over a year, to the public. Writing our own Base 64 encoder/decoder is definitely an option. Can even write it in C and compile it as a Python lib.

Answer (score 2):

Batteries included.

```
>>> import base64
>>> b64decode_autopadded = lambda b: base64.urlsafe_b64decode(b + '=='[:3 - len(b)%3])
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64encode("somedatastring\0\1").rstrip('=')
'c29tZWRhdGFzdHJpbmcAAQ'
>>> b64decode_autopadded("c29tZWRhdGFzdHJpbmcAAQ")
'somedatastring\x00\x01'
```

Comment: base64.urlsafe_b64encode("somedatastring1\0") == 'c29tZWRhdGFzdHJpbmcxAA=='`  Trying to avoid the == padding.

Comment: Read the question more carefully. I mention this solution but I have a LOT of 32 byte binary chunks that are independent so I would be stripping/adding the padding thousands, even millions of times a minute.